# Android list with ListAdapter layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android, list, layout, adapter

I'm working with android studio and I have this list and I can't get the layout to work.(You'll notice I have a listener that opens another activity when you click on a single item, and that works just fine).
Here's my activity_estoque.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the estoque.java class, that uses the .xml file above:

```
package com.example.asus.mingausfashionmoda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class estoque extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //string que pega do query
        String[] adobe_products = {"SANSUMG", "LG", "MOTOROLA", "Apple"};

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_estoque, R.id.label, adobe_products));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        //listening to single item in list view
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //selected item

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
                TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.label);
                final String product = tv.getText().toString();
                //String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                //lauching new activity to single item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), estoqueSingle.class);
                //sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
     }

}
```

I added some pictures to help you understand what I want and what I'm getting(sorry for bad paiting):
1 - The screen on the left is what I should see, according to the Android Studio activity_estoque.xml Design session, and the right one is what I actually get(Notice the "Mingau's fashion moda" thing missing, I really want this blue thing): ([What I should get vs what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzSSP.png))

2 - Now, the left screen is what I want, a top single button and the list bellow. The right one is what I'm receiving after adding a button on the activity_estoque.xml file(code bellow): ([What I want vs what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcnMz.png))

this is the activity_estoque.xml file after I add the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnttt"
        android:text="This is a button"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

First I thought that I should add a `setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque);`    on the `onCreat method`, like this:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque);
        //string que pega do query
        String[] adobe_products = {"SANSUMG", "LG", "MOTOROLA", "Apple"};
```

but if I do that I get the following error, and I'm not sure if it makes any sense to add this `setContentView...`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asus.mingausfashionmoda/com.example.asus.mingausfashionmoda.estoque}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

and this:

```
at com.example.asus.mingausfashionmoda.estoque.onCreate(estoque.java:20)
```

this is what I have on `estoque.java.20:`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque);
```

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: In ListActivity you must declare a ListView. And you are not doing this. Add a  ListView in your XML with default id

Comment: You mean, like this?
`protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        //string que pega do query
........`

Comment: Can you post your `activity_estoque.xml`?

Comment: Nope, keep your R.layout.estoque but in the XML declare a <ListView> attribute

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but the error is still on estoque.java.20(The same error I said before)
this is estoque.java
`protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque);

        ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);`

this is the xml edit(I kept the Textview):
`<ListView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/list"

        ></ListView>`
(To SaNtoRiaN, the activity_estoque.xml is already there)

Answer (score 0):

You are extending a ListActivity, so when you start the activity it will use the default layout.  If you try to do `setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque);` in the code then the activity will expect your layout to hava list view with the id "list".

Edit--
Change your layout to

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnttt"
        android:text="This is a button"
        />
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and

and `do setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque)` in onCreate

You will need to create a new layout for your list item view, which you need to pass to the ArrayAdapter
For eg:
activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then change this `this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_estoque, R.id.label, adobe_products));`  to `this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_test, R.id.label1, adobe_products));`

Comment: If I remove the `exetends ListActivity` I can't use this:
`this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_estoque, R.id.label, adobe_products));
        ListView lv = getListView();`

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges sorry missed your second screenshot, answer updated.

Comment: If I change the xml file to yours and don't add the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_estoque)`, I get the same result as on image 4(the one with multiple buttons). And if I add the `setCont...` I get the same error on `estoque.java.20` that I have said before... Do I have to do anything with the `ListView` on my `estoque.java` class I added on the xml file? Because I see no point in adding it if I'm not using it in my code;

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now the only thing missing is the blue bar at the top, if you have any idea how to use that I would appreciate, because I can see it on the design palette, but it doesn't show when I run the application... Thanks anyway :D

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges post the app theme and style what you are using.

Comment: The theme: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`
The style: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is explained here as example [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/7849-android-adventures-listview-and-adapters.html). And the blue bar above you see is actually achievable using Action Bar [example here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/). This action bar is configurable for color, icon, title, sub title and the menus(show/not to show).

Comment: Well, that's the tutorial I needed. If I can't get this to work I'll take a better look, thanks! And what I think is strange with that blue bar is that I can see it if I remove all this list code. It's like this List thing is using my entire page, and covering the blue bar. If I could set the list some pixels down, I think I would be able to see the blue bar and add the button I want. But if I add anything on the xml file it will repeat with the List...